# How to force a pop-up to open in a new window while (Always open pop-ups in new tab) is checked?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, popup, new-window

Currently, under IE8 and in IE7, using javascript window.open and target param is set to _blank, and while (Always open pop-ups in new tab) is checked, the pop up will open in new tab.

Is there a way to force the new pop up to open in a new window from javascript?
Is there a solution other than javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Do you think people who visit your website would be happy about this? I imagine they probably checked that option for a reason.

Comment: It is not a public application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  It's a user setting that you can't override from script on the page.  This is by design.

You could try using an HTML dialog instead if you truly need a dialog type experience.

Comment: Thanks. In this sense, is there a way to know whether the user had checked this setting or not?

Comment: Not from Javascript, no. Though I guess you could try to play games with checking the offsetWidth of the document... if it's the same as the parent, then it's probably a new tab?  May not be true on IE6 though.